# How do I specify LaTeX codes in Python 3.12 f-strings?

Tags: python, latex, f-string, python-3.12

How do I put LaTeX codes in a Python 3.12 f-string?

For example, the following `matplotlib` fragment now results in errors (`\` is a bad escape)

```py
bif.set_title(f"$x_n(r); , n\in {{ {bif_steps_min},\ldots,{bif_steps_min + bif_steps_show} }}$", fontsize=9, color='gray')
```

and if I avoid the error with

```py
bif.set_title(f"$x_n(r); , n\\in {{ {bif_steps_min},\\ldots,{bif_steps_min + bif_steps_show} }}$", fontsize=9, color='gray')
```

I just get "in" and "ldots" as text rather than the expected symbols (which I've had rendered successfully in the past).

How do I get the string generated by the f-string to include the full LaTeX symbol specification (e.g., `\ldots`)?

Comment: What is `bif`. Python itself doesn't understand LaTeX.  Some graphics output programs (such as matplotlib) do understand LaTex.  If `bif` isn't LaTex aware, then this isn't going to work.  It worked fine when I used pyplot.

Comment: There's nothing special about LaTex codes in f-strings. Construct them as you would any other f-string. The output will just be a normal string of codes though - Python will not render them into typeset output.

Comment: @Woodford That's not how it worked for me before. I was able to get the specified symbols (`\ldots`, and `\in`, in this case).

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes, good point. That's `matplotlib`. So Assuming that `matplotlib` can still render , for example, `\ldots` when it sees it, how do I now specify it in an f-string?

Comment: Whatever `bif` is might be rendering the LaTeX graphically for you but that has nothing to do with f-strings or any specific Python version.

Comment: @Woodford Yes it does: before 3.12 it worked, now it doesn't, because I have to change the way I use the "\" character, as shown in the OP: 3.12 f-strings don't like the old way (that worked), and the new way I tried that gets around 3.12's objections, "erases" the "\"  in the output.

Comment: I stand corrected. Here are the updates to f-string grammar in 3.12: https://peps.python.org/pep-0701/

Comment: @Woodford Yeah I had read that and thought I'd followed the new spec, but was still getting odd results. The second version (doubling the backslash) now works (*shrug*) but I can't find why that should work in the docs.